# Android Callable Wrapper fails to buid for Crosswalk project

Tags: android, xamarin, binding, crosswalk

I have created a binding project for the crosswalk project. It has created ACW code that fails to build

```
package mono.org.xwalk.core.internal;


public class XWalkSettingsInternal_ZoomSupportChangeListenerImplementor
    extends java.lang.Object
    implements
        mono.android.IGCUserPeer,
        org.xwalk.core.internal.XWalkSettingsInternal.ZoomSupportChangeListener
{
    static final String __md_methods;
    static {
        __md_methods = 
            "n_onGestureZoomSupportChanged:(ZZ)V:GetOnGestureZoomSupportChanged_ZZHandler:Org.Xwalk.Core.Internal.XWalkSettingsInternal/IZoomSupportChangeListenerInvoker, MethodCRM.Crosswalk\n" +
            "";
        mono.android.Runtime.register ("Org.Xwalk.Core.Internal.XWalkSettingsInternal+IZoomSupportChangeListenerImplementor, MethodCRM.Crosswalk, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null", XWalkSettingsInternal_ZoomSupportChangeListenerImplementor.class, __md_methods);
    }


    public XWalkSettingsInternal_ZoomSupportChangeListenerImplementor () throws java.lang.Throwable
    {
        super ();
        if (getClass () == XWalkSettingsInternal_ZoomSupportChangeListenerImplementor.class)
            mono.android.TypeManager.Activate ("Org.Xwalk.Core.Internal.XWalkSettingsInternal+IZoomSupportChangeListenerImplementor, MethodCRM.Crosswalk, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null", "", this, new java.lang.Object[] {  });
    }


    public void onGestureZoomSupportChanged (boolean p0, boolean p1)
    {
        n_onGestureZoomSupportChanged (p0, p1);
    }

    private native void n_onGestureZoomSupportChanged (boolean p0, boolean p1);

    java.util.ArrayList refList;
    public void monodroidAddReference (java.lang.Object obj)
    {
        if (refList == null)
            refList = new java.util.ArrayList ();
        refList.add (obj);
    }

    public void monodroidClearReferences ()
    {
        if (refList != null)
            refList.clear ();
    }
}
```

This is the build error that I have received.

**/Users/xxxxx/Integration/Mobile/MethodCRM/Droid/obj/Debug/android/src/mono/org/xwalk/core/internal/XWalkSettingsInternal_ZoomSupportChangeListenerImplementor.java(48,48): Error: error: ZoomSupportChangeListener is not public in XWalkSettingsInternal; cannot be accessed from outside package
org.xwalk.core.internal.XWalkSettingsInternal.ZoomSupportChangeListener
(MethodCRM.Droid)**

It seems like the compiler is complaining that org.xwalk.core.internal.XWalkSettingsInternal.ZoomSupportChangeListener is private interface but XWalkSettingsInternal_ZoomSupportChangeListenerImplementor is a public class. How do I resolve this error?

Update:
I have tried removing `XWalkSettingsInternal` and `XWalkSettingsInternal.ZoomSupportChangeListener` in Metadata.xml but that didn't resolve the issue.

```
<remove-node path="/api/package[@name='org.xwalk.core.internal']/class[@name='XWalkSettingsInternal']" />
<remove-node path="/api/package[@name='org.xwalk.core.internal']/interface[@name='XWalkSettingsInternal.ZoomSupportChangeListener']" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the CrossWalk wrapper in this GitHub project https://github.com/philieu/XamarinFormsXWalkViewTest and it works, so maybe you could look at that to see what you are doing differently?

Update: I looked through the CrossWalk source and I don't see anywhere that `XWalkSettingsInternal` is exposed publicly by other classes, so I would just remove that node completely.

This link may be helpful http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/12627/java-binding-member-cannot-be-accessed-from-outside-package

Comment: That's funny. I'm actually using the same binding project as well and it's using Crosswalk v15. I'm trying to upgrade this project to Crosswalk v18 to resolve some bugs but I'm stuck because I can't figure out how to resolve the build error in my question.

Comment: I have tried removing `XWalkSettingsInternal` but that didn't work (more details in my updated question).

Answer (score 0):

Please note that when you look through the source code of Crosswalk and see some classes named `xxInternal.java` in the package `org.xwalk.core.internal`, these classes are NOT externally exposed interface.

When you building source code of Crosswalk, there is a script that translates `org.xwalk.core.internal.xxInternal.java` to `org.xwalk.core.xx.java` automatically, which is the final interface to the developers. Although there is a one-to-one correspondence between this pair of files, they are not exactly the same. Only the method marked by `@XWalkAPI` in `xxInternal.java` will remain in `xx.java`.

You can check the final interface via official [API docs](https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/apis/embedding_api.html), or by decompiling `xwalk_core_library.jar`, which could be found in the AAR file you're using.